# Serialize object to a file

Tags: java, file, serialization

I have some basic class, that stores data:

```
class Item implements java.io.Serializable {
    String this.data = "";
    public void saveData(String data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
    public String getData() {
        return this.data;
    }
}
```

And a function in the other class, which is supposed to save Item instance to a file:

```
    private static void saveItemToFile(File folder, Item item) throws IOException{
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(
            folder.getAbsolutePath() + item.getData() + ".obj");
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
    oos.writeObject(item);
    oos.close();
}
```

Testing code:

```
Item itm = new Item();
itm.saveData("String data here");
File folder = new File(System.getProperty("user.home") + "/.CDDB");
saveItemToFile(folder, itm);
```

But this code is not working. There's no any error or exception raised, but it just does not create file in the specified folder. What is my mistake?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: String this.data = ""; ??

Comment: Please show your entire code for the last part; you have to be handling `IOException` somewhere, but I don't see it, and I suspect you're swallowing an exception that is being thrown (likely `folder` doesn't exist). Also, debug and inspect the value of `folder` before the `saveItemToFile` call, and inspect the value being passed to `new FileOutputStream`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your destination path is built by adding the file name to the directory path without path separator:

```
folder.getAbsolutePath() + item.getName() + ".obj"
```

So you should have a file called `[USER_HOME]/.CDDB[item name].obj`

Better use `File` objects directly instead:

```
private static void saveItemToFile(File folder, Item item) throws IOException {
    File file = new File(folder, item.getName() + ".obj");
    try (ObjectOutputStream oos =
            new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file))) {
        oos.writeObject(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code works perfectly woks, may be your looking for wrong folder for generated file. Only thing is it append `.CDDB` along with file name. If you are not able to locate user.home folder,add below line to print where does object serailiaze object.

```
System.out.println("--- output path "+System.getProperty("user.home"));
```

Otherwise create `File` object with a parameter `System.getProperty("user.home") + "/.CDDB"` and pass to OutputStream

Answer (score 0):

I have compiled an ran your program, and this is what I observed:

A file was created with a name of `.CDDBString data here.obj`

I think you intended a file called `String data here.obj` but in `saveItemToFile` you are concatenating the folder and filenames together to get a filename, without a path separator.

This should do the trick:

```
private static void saveItemToFile(File folder, Item item) throws IOException{
  File out = new File(folder, item.getData() + ".obj");
  FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(out);
  ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
  oos.writeObject(item);
  oos.close();
}
```